# Why are there different number of propeller blades on the inboard and outboard engines?

Tags: aircraft-design, aviation-history, propeller

The Junkers G 38 has four propeller blades on the inboard but only two on the outboard engines.

What's the reason for this special arrangement and is there any benefit?

[image: Ju-38]

Comment: Your illustration is a drawing by Bruce McCall. His books are very, very funny. I don't recognize this one, but he did create some other WWII aircraft. One had locomotive wheels because of the rubber shortage, Another had a droopy nose because its engineering drawings slipped in the blueprint copier. My favorite was a fighter trainer with lots of student seats, in a line, and one instructor seat. He also wrote an article on golf carts of the Third Reich.

Comment: @stretch Someone else edited the question and added the picture; I've always thought that it was a photograph. But looking at it more closely now I can imagine it to be a drawing. Beautiful artwork. We do know that it depicts a real aircraft from the 1920s well into the 1930s. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Of course it is a photograph... It is cropped from a larger one that can be found in the internet, and signed... https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-SMGqavIFKx0/Vs9VJR-wWUI/AAAAAAAEJ5M/yid3NLjsQg4/s1600/12772058_1051779854860746_6975732121574380789_o.jpg

Comment: @xxavier Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The inboard engines were of a different type, and more powerful than the outboard engines. Hence, the props had to absorb different power, so they were four-bladed for the inboard and two-bladed for the outboard engines.

Yo can see the specs of the airplane here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_G.38#Specifications_(G.38_1929)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info. I had never heard of a multi with different engines. You learn something on this list every day :)

Answer (score 13):

What's interesting is the why. In essence this plane is powered by 6 identical engines, which helps with the parts commonality and maintenance.

Owing to the financial difficulties of the interwar period, the inboard bigger engines (L55) are a *doubled* version of the outboard ones (L8a): an [inline-six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight-six_engine) configuration turned into V12. Which helps save weight and structural reinforcing, and delivers the right amount of power.

Speaking of doubling an engine, [you can double a V12](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/32641/14897).

Junkers had the L2 engine in 1925, it was enlarged to become the L5 (with license from BMW). The L8 is a higher power L5. And the L55 is a double L5. It's a good engineering solution to the lack of engine diversity.

The aircraft was later upgraded to have 4 identical [Jumo 204](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Jumo_204) diesel engines, the original configuration (L55 and L8) was petrol.